# Cucumber run time exception

Tags: cucumber

this question is the duplicate post. the reason i ask is I couldn't get a valid answer (or at least the answer that i could understand) from them
    hence I am asking again.

below is the code.there is an executable RunnerTest and a baseClass

```
  @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
        @CucumberOptions(plugin = {"html:target/whisper-html-report", "json:target/whisper_report.json", "com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:output/report.html"},tags = {"@Tag"})
        public class RunnerTest {
        }

public class BaseClass {
@Before
    public void startUp() {
        try {
            driver = webModel.getUtils().browser();
            driver.get(webModel.getUtils().getProperty("url"));
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

@After
    public void tearDown(Scenario scenario) throws IOException {
        if (scenario.isFailed()) {
            TakesScreenshot camera = (TakesScreenshot) driver;
            byte[] screenshot = camera.getScreenshotAs(BYTES);
            scenario.embed(screenshot, "image/png");
            System.out.println("screenShot taken");
       }
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
    }
}


      Feature file
        @Tag
        Feature: will this run
          Scenario: try to execute feature
          Given I feel like running the code
          Then I run the code

        Step definition-

        import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
        import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;

        public class run_this_MyStepdefs {
            @Given("^I feel like running the code$")
            public void iFeelLikeRunningTheCode()  {
                System.out.println("yes i feel like running the code");
            }

            @Then("^I run the code$")
            public void iRunTheCode()
            {
                System.out.println("hence i am running the code");

            }
        }
```

below us the error code

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Failed to instantiate classBaseClass
```

Comment: Raj, you can't simply post an error message and expect someone to know your answer without seeing your code. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more guidance

Comment: Hello guys sincere apologies for my partial question. i can totally understand your frustration and anger.  i have formatted my question with proper code for your kind perusal. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think it's got something to do with workspace.xml

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to instantiate the base class, and this was the reason for the cucumber exceptions.

The moment I removed the base class object, all seemed to work fine.